# Can't connect to google apis on android wear

Tags: wear-os

I am having trouble to update the code I wrote that was working with the google play services 6.5.87, to the newer version 8.4.0.

I decided to create a little project and just log everything that occures in my listener.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CONNECTED TO API");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "NOT CONNECTED TO API");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection to google services failed!" + result);
}


@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DATA CHANGED");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    int conResult = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if(conResult!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Log.e(TAG,"Google play services are not available on this device");
    }

    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();

    if (mApiClient != null && !(mApiClient.isConnected() || mApiClient.isConnecting()))
        mApiClient.connect();
    Log.d(TAG, "mApiClient : " + mApiClient);

    //Listener to check connection with the mobile (bluetooth enabled/disabled and device detected)
    super.onCreate();
}
```

the gradle file on the wear side :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.app.testproject"
      minSdkVersion 21
      targetSdkVersion 23
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }

}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
}
```

those are the logs I have :

```
02-03 15:55:47.601    5431-5431/? E/WearMessageListenerService﹕ Google play services are not available on this device
02-03 15:55:47.673    5431-5431/? D/WearMessageListenerService﹕ mApiClient : com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj@12dbffce
```

I am using a Moto360.

Comment: Well, to those who have that issue, allow the updates on your phone (if some updates were blocked) and this should resolve it

Comment: What version of GMS does your watch have installed? And do you really need to be targeting 8.4.0? There's some relevant discussion at https://plus.google.com/+HansKratz/posts/6DwaRHK1z39

Comment: I need a version upper or equal to 8.3.0 (change in the synchronization of assets), but I correctly detect the api, I had a lot of updates to do on my android phone and it must have corrected that